# Adding a TextView to a fragment in onClick() (inner class)

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, inner-classes

I am attempting to programmatically add a TextView to a fragment once an item has been clicked. However, when I try my code it throws a NullPointerException.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

mAddTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
mAddTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout thisRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_relative_layout);

            TextView random = new TextView(getActivity());
            random.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            ));

            random.setText("New Text Box");

            createSingleEventThis.addView(
                    random
            );
        }
    });
```

Comment: use `getView()` instead of `getActivity()`

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem!!